# Change the color and background of the Kivy progressbar

Tags: python, kivy

I am using the following function to implement a progressbar with kivy.

```
kv = '''
FloatLayout:
    Starfield:
        id: sf
        progress: pb
    ProgressBar:
        id: pb
        pos_hint: {'right':1.0, 'top':1.0}
        size_hint: (0.25, 0.1)
'''
```

I would like to change the color and background of the progressbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own version of `ProgressBar` using dynamic classes in your `kv` like this:

```
<-MyProgressBar@ProgressBar>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        BorderImage:
            border: (12, 12, 12, 12)
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
            size: self.width, 24
            source: 'pb_bg.png'
        BorderImage:
            border: [int(min(self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 12))] * 4
            pos: self.x, self.center_y - 12
            size: self.width * (self.value / float(self.max)) if self.max else 0, 24
            source: 'pb_fg.png'
```

Which is just the `ProgressBar` entry from `style.kv` with different sources for the `BorderImages`. Then you can just use `MyProgressBar` instead of `ProgressBar` later in the `kv`.

Here is the `pb_fg.png` image:

[image: pb_fg.png]

And here is the `pb_bg.png` image:

[image: pb_bg.png]

These images are just copies of the default images used by the `ProgressBar`, with some colors changed.

Comment: You're a genius, many thanks. Where did you find the png files? How do I get them in different colors?

Comment: I created the png files by editing the default images that the `ProgresBar` uses (They are in the `defaulttheme-0.png` in `dist-packages/kivy/data/images` in the python installation). If you want to use one of the default images, you can replace `pb_bg.png` with `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/progressbar_background` or replace `pb_fg.png` with `atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/progressbar` in your `kv`. Don't know what you mean by "not suitable" images.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are really helping me.